# How do I do an angular js jasmine unit test for a service promise?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

How do I do an angular js jasmine unit test for a service promise?

I'm using angular version 1 with javascript es6 promise.

I want to test the code below, what is the best way?

**Here is my current service I want to test with a unit test:**

```
var testGet = function() {      
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {           
        resolve("completed");   
    });
};
```

I want to test that it returns a response of "completed" in a resolve promise callback.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you seen the docs? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#testing

Comment: Just had a read of that documentation. Seems good but how do I call testGet?

Comment: You would inject your service and call it. Using the example, you would basically replace `$q` with your service and function call.

Comment: in angular, use the $q service for promises.
see example: https://jsfiddle.net/ronapelbaum/nd8t4ef0/